# File recovery of windows after installing ubuntu

Tags: data-recovery, partitioning

In one of my computers I  installed ubuntu 14.04. Actually , I tried to dual-boot in along with windows 7 and I tried to do the partition during the ubuntu installation procedure.

Now all of my 500 GB hard disk has been occupied by ubuntu and I cannot access windows. Since, I have all my documents in windows and I want to recover it. Will I be able to recovery my files of windows ? If yes, can you please help me with the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You must be aware of these facts:

- Try to preserve the disk space you have, otherwise you will loose the recoverable portion
- You can use a powerful tool called `photorec` to recover your files.
- The files must be recovered to a another storage device.

[Here is a tutorial on how to use photorec.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EJdx2ORi3r4)